# Xamarin Forms WebView loading mixed content in Android

Tags: android, xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms, mixed-content

I have a Xamarin Forms WebView. The Source is a Webpage which contains mixed content (links to https and http resources). It loads in Xamarin Forms iOS without problems, however in Android it will not load, and I suspect that the problems is the mixed content.

How can I set MixedContentMode?

There is documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.platformconfiguration.androidspecific.webview.setmixedcontentmode?view=xamarin-forms

But I don't understand how to use that. Can someone give me an example?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

It depends a little bit if you have defined your `WebView` in code or XAML.

If you defined it in code, make sure you have a reference to it by the variable name, for instance:

`var myWebView = new WebView();`

`myWebView` is what I am talking about in this case.

Then, include this using at the top of your class:

`using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;`

Then add this line after you have initialized the `WebView`:

`myWebView.On<Android>().SetMixedContentMode(MixedContentHandling.AlwaysAllow);`

From XAML, add the right namespace to the root of your page, like this:

`<ContentPage xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core" ....>`

Then, on your `WebView`, you can just add another attribute: `<WebView ... android:WebView.MixedContentMode="AlwaysAllow" />`

These are the so-called platform-specifics. You can set platform-specific properties directly from Xamarin.Forms shared code as opposed to having a custom renderer in place for one simple property.

Read more on it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/platform-specifics/ and consuming (this specific case, actually) here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/platform-specifics/consuming/android#enabling-mixed-content-in-a-webview

A note on the actual thing you are setting here, in the example I simply set it to `AlwaysAllow`, ensure you know what each option does and set it to the most secure one. Here is a small explanation, taken from the Microsoft Docs:

> - `AlwaysAllow` – indicates that the `WebView` will allow an HTTPS origin to load content from an HTTP origin.
> - `NeverAllow` – indicates that the `WebView` will not allow an HTTPS origin to load content from an HTTP origin.
> - `CompatibilityMode` – indicates that the `WebView` will attempt to be compatible with the approach of the latest device web browser. Some
>     HTTP content may be allowed to be loaded by an HTTPS origin and other
>     types of content will be blocked. The types of content that are
>     blocked or allowed may change with each operating system release.

Comment: Tanks for the clear explanation. However, SettingMixedContentMode in code or in XAML does not resolve the issue. What else could be the problem?

Comment: You should probably closely inspect the application output while running. It is nearly impossible to say with this little information, sorry.

Comment: Application Output: [WebViewFactory] Loading com.android.chrome version 70.0.3538.80 (code 353808052)
[zygote64] Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<uO>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/TracingController;

Comment: [X509Util] Failed to validate the certificate chain, error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Comment: Ok, so it seems the certificate is not valid. Can you share the URL? Or is that not possible?

Comment: I see a couple of fonts are loaded over HTTP. Do you own the site? Can you change it? Still, the mixed-content should work for this

Comment: Could you please help me with this issue? I'm loading a domain through HTTPS, which itself needs to load images through HTTP. I tried using both the XAML method and the Fluent API method, but I can't seem to get it to work. I keep getting the same error message: "Mixed Content: The page at 'website' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image...".